# Python, Pymongo: Create a User for a DataBase with read only privilege

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying to create a user for a database , that would have read-only access,
I tried the following

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongo=MongoClient()
mongo.test.command("createUser", "testing", pwd="testing", roles=["read"])
```

Then I authenticate

```
mongo.test.authenticate('testing', 'testing')
```

However if I try to insert a document, it actually does insert:

```
mongo.test.test.insert_one({'name':'vincent'})
```

The command `mongo.test.command("usersInfo")` returns

```
{'ok': 1.0,
 'users': [{'_id': 'test.testing',
   'db': 'test',
   'roles': [{'db': 'test', 'role': 'read'}],
   'user': 'testing'}]}
```

Which seems to indicate  that the user has been created properly.
What should I do in order to create and authenticate with a read-only user that would see his insert requests rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Restart your mongo instance with access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#re-start-the-mongodb-instance-with-access-control)

```
mongod --auth --config <config_path>
```

Or enable [`security.authorization`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization) in your configuration file.

```
security:
  autorization: enabled
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Other question:is it possible to create a user that have certain priviliges for all databases? And not an a per database basis?

Comment: Although this may defy security best practices .i.e. [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) you can [create a custom role for multiple resources (some or all databases, an entire cluster, some or all collections)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createRole/#dbcmd.createRole).

Comment: Great thx! now it works. Last question: Now i created a user with read/write privileges on all db with  `mongo.admin.command("createUser", "man", pwd="man", roles=["readWriteAnyDatabase"])` . I can connect using that user with  `MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@127.0.0.1' % ('man', 'man'))` . All this works. Now I want to create a test for that new connection. I assign the MongoClient to the variable name `mongo`. Is there any attribute of `mongo` showing the username and the role?I know i can see that from the `mongo.adminsystem.users` but can i see it on the mongoclient instance?

Comment: You can run a [`connectionStatus` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/connectionStatus/#dbcmd.connectionStatus) _e.g._ `mongo.admin.command('connectionStatus')`